# Why is setting a variable name giving me "command not found"?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, variable, arithmetic

I want to input a number and then add taxes and subtract discounts.

I am trying:

```
#!/bin/sh
...
final_amount = $(echo "$purchase_amount+($purchase_amount * $tax)-($purchase_amount * $discount)" |bc -l)
...
```

but I'm getting:

```
$ . 3_purchase_amounts.sh 
...
final_amount: command not found
...
```

Comment: So am I. FWIW you should quote your variables and protect against empty input. Consider if someone enters {nothing} for the purchase amount. Your next line as written will then get processed by the shell to read as `if test  -lt 1000`. You could change that line to read `if test "${purchase_amount:-0}" -lt 1000` so that an empty `$purchase_amount` was replaced by `0`. Better yet, insert something like `test -z "$purchase_amount" && echo "Need a purchase amount" >&2 && exit 1` immediately after the `read`

Comment: shell is very weak and lame interpreter. Little here and there and it fails. You got to watch even all white spaces in script. My script was failing because of invisible line feed character. Probably this is only scripting language where white spaces count matters!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not put spaces around the "=" character in the `final_amount` line: variable assignment in shells does not support such spaces because this would conflict with things like `command_name = arg2`. As you could see, the shell tried to execute a `final_amount` command and you got the error:

```
final_amount: command not found
```